# Find tasks with one value that are earlier than the earliest task with another value

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

I've been trying to forge a select which will capture table rows with service_name column ="VALUE1" being modified earlier than the earliest row with service_name column = "VALUE2", where their task_id column is equal

So far I have everything but the last condition

```
select 
  * 
from 
  test s1 
where (s1.service_name='VALUE1' 
      and s1.X_MODIFY_DATE < (select 
                                * 
                              FROM (select modify_date 
                                   from test s2 
                                   where s2.service_name='VALUE2' 
                                   order by s2.modify_date desc) 
                              where rownum <2)) ;
```

Obviously, adding        `where s1.task_id = s2.task_id`   won't work.

Is there any simple way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I would think that this should accomplish your goal:

```
select
  s1.*
from
  test s1
  inner join (select 
                min(X_MODIFY_DATE) as X_MODIFY_DATE, service_name, task_id
              from
                test
              where service_name = 'VALUE2'
              group by service_name, task_id) s2 on s1.X_MODIFY_DATE > s2.X_MODIFY_DATE 
                                                and s1.service_name = 'VALUE1' 
                                                and s1.task_id = s2.task_id
```

This will get all the `s1` records that have a modify date less than the *earliest* `s2` date, but still have the same `task_id` with the values set for each.

Comment: Sometimes a single row is duplicated few times while using Your solution, not sure why

Comment: @SSV That'll be because you have more than one record that meets the join criteria.  I'm sure its the date range causing this.  Compare `s2.*` to `s1.*` and you should see why its creating dupes in `s1`

Comment: @SSV, that doesnt mean that duplicates in `s1` are a bad thing.  If you dont expect them tho, we'll need to add another condition, or restrict the conditions you have.  Do you really want *ALL* the task id's that are less than the date? or do you maybe want the earliest or latest one?

Comment: Oh, I want only records which s1.X_MODIFY_DATE is less than EARLIEST s2.X_MODIFY_DATE, not all of them (there might be more than 1 of it)

That attempt is visible in my original select (more specifially - in a subselect)

Comment: it throws an error for
s2.X_MODIFY_DATE invalid identifier

Comment: I forgot the alias on the subselect.  Edited

Comment: Now it outputs 0 results. Also 0 when I change greater sign to opposite. And I know there are at least few results which should be displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66766/discussion-between-paqogomez-and-ssv).

Comment: @SSV, left some instructions on fiddles in the chat.  Let me know if i can help more on monday.

Comment: still no solution, I gave up. Upvoted tho for help :)

Comment: @SSV no reason to give up.  I'm sure there was just a misunderstanding in what you wanted.  Did you ever make a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You might try the following:

```
WITH s2 AS (
    SELECT task_id, MIN(x_modify_date) AS min_modify_date
      FROM test
     WHERE service_name = 'VALUE2'
     GROUP BY task_id
)
SELECT s1.* FROM test s1, s2
 WHERE s1.service_name = 'VALUE1'
   AND s1.task_id = s2.task_id
   AND s1.x_modify_date < s2.min_modify_date;
```

Here I am using the `WITH` clause to create an alias for a subquery giving the minimum modify date by `task_id`. One caveat is that no records will be returned if there aren't any 'VALUE2' records for a given `task_id` in `TEST`.

Comment: It shows some records where "service_name column ="VALUE1" IS NOT being modified earlier than the earliest row with service_name column = "VALUE2""

Thanks for help tho :)